# Access to live stream from Nest Cam

Tags: nest-api

I'm the developer on a comprehensive Apple TV app for the Nest called Feather (featherapp.co). One issue that I've run into is that users are expecting to be able to view the live feed of their cameras.

Has anyone determined any way of accessing the live feed of the camera? I've done quite a bit of reverse engineering but I believe the stream itself is protected by some sort of DRM.

It looks like it's an RTMP stream that takes a format like below:

rtmps://oculus387-vir.dropcam.com/nexus/[cameraid]

with some parameters

_sessionToken,_isHD,_camera.uuid,time

I've tried a number of things but I'm never really able to establish a connection to the source. I'm a little out of my depth here, as an application developer getting into the more hardcore streaming technology. Any insight would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This should now be possible with [Device Access](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access).

> **GenerateRtspStream**
>
> Request a token to access an RTSP live stream URL.
>
> RTSP live stream URLs cannot be shared between clients. A stream URL can only be used by one client at a time. If multiple clients want to stream from the same camera at the same time, RTSP commands must be sent for each individual client, and each individual client must use its own stream URL.

Source: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatertspstream

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the live stream using an API.

Comment: I know the API doesn't officially support it, but by scraping the page and doing some research it should theoretically be possible right? Is there anyone I can get in touch with at Nest to get a special allowance for the Apple TV? It's clearly a killer feature, and until they release their own app (and kill mine) it would be in their best interest.

Comment: Camera's that have enabled public viewing technically can be iframed, but there is no pragmatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't acesses the live stream in any normal way but you may be able to get one frame per second from the old android api. I have tried this but i think they patched it or it doesn't work with the new cameras

```
#! /bin/bash
i=00
while [ $i -lt 300 ]
do
curl 'https://home.nest.com/dropcam/api/cameras/_your camera url etc' -H 'Cookie: YOUR_COOKIE ETC'  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: https://home.nest.com/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed -o nest\ testing/$i.jpeg
let i+=1
echo $i
done
ffmpeg -r 25 -start_number 1 -f image2 -i "%04d.jpg" -vcodec png video.avi
o.avi
```