# Nest live camera stream

Tags: c#, android, ios, video-streaming, nest-api

I'm UNITY developer and working on application for mobile devices (iOS and Android) that need to connect the Nest cameras and view the cameras' feed. I'm using C# to code and need to know about any sdk for this or suggestions. 
I looked here: [Access to live stream from Nest Cam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206983/access-to-live-stream-from-nest-cam) and the answer is quite understandable.
I installed the Nest app, it has the feature (Nest camera feed view) exactly what i need. 
Can you kindly help me with implementation of this feature in my app?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Attempt the problem, then return with any problems you encounter along with way.

Comment: Accessing the live stream is not possible. The only way to do it right now is to make a camera 100% public to the world and use the iframe provided on the page to embed the player somewhere. This functionality is not certifiable by the Works with Nest program.