# Is it possible to stream to youtube from wired nest cam indoor?

Tags: nest-device-access

I have recently purchased a Nest Camera (Wired, Indoor) today and I am wanting to stream it to Youtube so I can embed a live-feed into my website and so I can share the stream with my friends so I do not have to add them to the Google Home application and give them access to all devices.

I've seen the api documents for it, but I do not understand them. I found the API Documents on google's developer site (https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/camera-wired#extend_a_live_stream), however I do not understand how this works, or how to complete it.

In my personal opinion, there should be a feature to stream it to a platform such as Youtube, such a feature would make things a lot easier for many people.

I have so far found no documents explaining how to do this except from the api documents.

Comment: Looks like the documentation tells you what to do. Can you be specific what part is unclear or what you need help with? Also, what programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure... I'm trying to make it stream to youtube.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to live stream from Nest Cam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206983/access-to-live-stream-from-nest-cam)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple "out of the box" way to do this.  You would need to setup some kind of device as an intermediary.  One one side it would connect to the SDM API, open a stream, and start receiving the data.  On the other side it would need to connect to the YouTube API (or equivalent) and pass the data through.  Unfortunately you would need some degree of programming skill to engineer such as system.

Comment: Why "unfortunately"? This is a computer programming site. The assumption is that you already have some degree of programming skill. If you're looking for a non-programming solution, then the site you want is superuser.com.

Comment: Based on the candor of the question it appeared as if the author was looking for a non-programming solution.